# How to get rememberMe and JSESSIONID after authentication using Apache Shiro packege

Tags: grails, shiro

I'm using Apache Shiro library for enabling security for my web application.
I'm using login method and after successful login, Shiro generating JSESSIONID and rememberMe and adding to the cookies. I want to retrieve these two(JSESSIONID  and rememberMe using some of the Shiro service or some logic kind of code.)

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: They are just cookies, you should be able to pull them out of the servlet request (or equivalent).  But you probably _shouldn't_ interact with those cookies directly, but instead, use Shiro's API.

Comment: @BrianDemers, Using Shiro API Can you please provide some sample code.

Comment: @user6097055 Your question isn't clear, what are you trying to do? 
Samples: https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples
You might also want to ask more general questions on the user list: https://shiro.apache.org/mailing-lists.html